# Is there a fetched callback to Relay.createContainer?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js

It seems that at the moment it is not possible to provide a callback to `Relay.createContainer` which will be called when the initial and all following data is fetched.

In my example I need to know a value of the initially fetched data outside of the `render` function of my wrapped component.

It should be possible to supply a callback to the `Relay.createContainer` function that gets called whenever data was fetched and before the wrapped component gets updated.

If this is already possible can you please give an example?

Comment: Will the `componentWillUpdate` function within the React component work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with standard React lifecycle callbacks: `componentWillMount` is called the first time a component mounts and before it renders, and `componentWillReceiveProps` is called thereafter whenever new props (including Relay data) are passed to the component.